# How can I enable / disable DSA in JDK?

Tags: java, security, ssl

**ENVIRONMENT:** Java version `1.8.0_171`

**SITUATION:**

Created Certificate with DSA 1024 (Thanks for reference [OpenSSL generate different types of self signed certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/openssl-generate-different-types-of-self-signed-certificate?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)). 
Enabled SSL and my web site available from https.

**TASK:**
I wanted to enable/disable site availability for DSA 1024.

**ACTION:**

***1.Created Certificate with DSA 1024.***

```
 openssl dsaparam -genkey 1024 -out dsakey.pem
 openssl req -x509 -new -key dsakey.pem -out dsacert.crt
```

***2.Generated Keystore***

```
 keytool -genkeypair -alias sportal -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024 -keystore keystore.jks
```

***3.Created Certificate Request***

```
 keytool -certreq -v -alias sportal -file csr-for-myserver.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

***4.Sign Certificate Request Using ROOT CA***

```
 openssl x509 -req -in csr-for-myserver.pem -CA dsacert.crt -CAkey dsakey.pem -CAcreateserial -out signed-cert.pem
```

***5. Import Signed Certificate To Keystore***

```
 keytool -import -v -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias cacert -file signed-cert.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

***6. Modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` in java.security***

*a.* Modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=DSA keySize < 1024` then from browser called web site -> site not available.

*b.* Modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=DSA` then from browser called web site  ->  site not available.

*c.* Modified `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=` then from browser called web site  ->  site not available.

**RESULT:**

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1666)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:318)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.chooseCipherSuite(ServerHandshaker.java:1115)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientHello(ServerHandshaker.java:807)
    at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(ServerHandshaker.java:228)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$1.run(Handshaker.java:989)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker$DelegatedTask.run(Handshaker.java:1467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.tasks(SecureNioChannel.java:407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshakeUnwrap(SecureNioChannel.java:467)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.handshake(SecureNioChannel.java:232)
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

**QUESTION:**

Why :) ?

Comment: What browser? Current Chrome and Firefox don't support ciphersuites using DSA (which TLS calls DSS), and I don't know about Edge. Turn on javax.net.debug=ssl to get a trace and check, or use Wireshark or similar. Also the commands you show will use the keytool-generated dummy selfsigned cert, not the openssl-signed one, although in this case both are the same algorithm and size.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox shows the same error message as I added above. IE shows some additional info when running via `javax.net.debug=all`.
`certpath: AlgorithmChecker.contains: SHA1withDSA`
`Provider: MessageDigest.SHA-256 algorithm from: SUN`
`Provider: KeyGenerator.SunTlsExtendedMasterSecret algorithm from: SunJCE`
`Provider: MessageDigest.MD5 algorithm from: SUN`
`Provider: MessageDigest.SHA algorithm from: SUN`

Comment: BTW: Locally I tried this example https://airbrake.io/blog/java-exception-handling/sslhandshakeexception and checked it for RSA and DSA it works but when I restrict via RSA or DSA, when I am using keySize restriction it doesn't works. It just works with keySize for EC.

Comment: AFAIK Chrome and Firefox do not support DSA (DSS) based ciphers anymore. Check it yourself: [List supported ciphers of your browser](https://cc.dcsec.uni-hannover.de/)